# How do I interrupt deployment / reject application in Tomcat?

Tags: java, tomcat, war

I'm trying to verify some conditions on application startup, such as the presence of critical files in the system.
To do this, I'm using a SerlvetContextListener, which tests for a bunch of conditions on startup.

How can I make so that the application rejects the deployment in Tomcat, if any of these conditions is not met? I could throw an exception, and catch that in the logs, but I'd like the application not to start at all.
Even failing Tomcat service startup would be a solution.

What's the simplest way? Should I try connecting to the Tomcat manager and undeploy the app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well...

According to your original question, you'd like the application to "not start at all" if certain files aren't there (or other conditions aren't met). Logically, it follows that the checking of the conditions can't possibly be a part of the application (if the checking is to be done as a part of the application - say, upon startup - then the application must be started for those checks to take place).

So:

1. If you don't want the application to start *at all* unless certain conditions are met, then your solution must be external to the application. For example, you could write your own Tomcat startup script that will check for your conditions first, and only then start Tomcat up.
2. If you don't mind the application starting and performing the checks, then the `ServletContextListener` is precisely what you should take advantage of. Throwing an exception from within `contextInitialized()` will result in the application being "unavailable" for serving requests. Alternatively, you could communicate with Tomcat's MBeans to stop the application if checks don't pass.

Comment: Yes, you got me there. What I'd like is the application being unavailable, and I wasn't aware of the behavior of Tomcat when throwing an exception during app initialization. Let me try!

Comment: Actually that's not a Tomcat-specific thing. The Servlet specification mandates that unhandled exceptions thrown from context initializers will result in errors trying to access the application.